# Kotlin - com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider Error

Tags: android, kotlin, xiaomi

basically i have a fragment and in this fragment user can pick a image or use camera to take photo and i am taking the photo as uri and save to the local DB as string . And show the photo in this fragment.

This code works fine until i destroy my app in my xiaomi device. After i try to reach the uri from db and show in the fragment, app crashes. Btw this is not happening in emulator, everything is fine. I read some blogs and this could be happen in Mi devices but did not find a solution. The code;

```
class ProfilePageFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding : FragmentProfilePageBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var routineTasksViewModel: RoutineTasksViewModel

    private var userName : String? = null
    private var userProfilePhotoUri : String? = null

    private lateinit var cameraPermissions : Array<String>
    private lateinit var storagePermissions : Array<String>
    private var imageUri : Uri? = null

    private companion object {
        private const val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100
        private const val STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 101

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentProfilePageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        routineTasksViewModel = (activity as MainActivity).routineTasksViewModel

        cameraPermissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        storagePermissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        getUserProfileInformations()


        binding.apply {
            profilePhotoIV.setOnClickListener{
                showInputImageDialog()

            }

        }

    }



    //popUp menu and item click funcs
    private fun showInputImageDialog() {
        val popUpMenu = PopupMenu(requireContext(),binding.profilePhotoIV)
        popUpMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,1, R.string.camera)
        popUpMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,2,2, R.string.gallery)

        popUpMenu.show()

        popUpMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            val id = menuItem.itemId
            if (id ==1){
                if (checkCameraPermission()){
                    pickImageCamera()
                }else{
                    requestCameraPermission()
                }

            }else if(id == 2){

                if (checkStoragePermission()){
                    pickImageGallery()
                }else{
                    requestStoragePermission()
                }
            }

            return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
        }

    }

    //two funcs check the permissions
    private fun checkStoragePermission() : Boolean { //permissionGranted -> true
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun checkCameraPermission() : Boolean{ //permissionGranted -> true
        val cameraResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        val storageResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        return cameraResult && storageResult
    }
    //

    private fun pickImageGallery(){
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"

        galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    private fun pickImageCamera(){
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Sample Title")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Sample Description")

        imageUri = activity?.contentResolver?.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)


        cameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)

    }

    //launcher to camera
    private val cameraActivityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
            if ( result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                //image came from camera
                binding.profilePhotoIV.setImageURI(imageUri)
                updateProfilePhotoToDB(imageUri)
            }else{
                //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), R.string.permissions_required, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    //launcher to gallery
    private val galleryActivityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
            if ( result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                val data = result.data
                imageUri = data!!.data

                binding.profilePhotoIV.setImageURI(imageUri)
                updateProfilePhotoToDB(imageUri)

            }else{
                //Toast.makeText(requireContext(), R.string.permissions_required, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }

    private fun requestStoragePermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(),storagePermissions, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    private fun requestCameraPermission()  {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(),cameraPermissions, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)

    }

    //when we request to take permission, according to request code pickImageCamera or pickImageGallery will work.
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        when (requestCode){
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()){
                    val cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    val storageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

                    if (cameraAccepted && storageAccepted){
                        pickImageCamera()
                    }
                }
            }

            STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()){
                    val storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    if (storageAccepted){
                        pickImageGallery()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: "After i try to reach the uri from db" -- generally speaking, you cannot persist `Uri` values, as [your rights to access the content are short-lived](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you suggest me a proper way to do this, is there any solution or do i have to upload the images to a server like firebase? I need to take the image and save to local db.

Comment: Once you get the `Uri`, copy the contents to a file that you control, using `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. Then, your database can point to that file, rather than to the original `Uri`.